# How do you use Domain Events without obfuscating the control flow?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event, reverse-engineering

When we have a system which utilizes Domain Events, it can be quite hard to comprehend the whole workflow (sequence of events) of processing a particular command: how many active handlers we have, how many other events they give raise to, and so on.

On the other hand procedural workflow of Transaction Script is much easier to follow in code. In our team this argument carries much weight, and that's why straightforward Transaction Script is in favor.

I am looking for any approaches that might help eliminate this shortcoming of the Domain Events design pattern.

Comment: Since "comprehensible" can be vague and subjective, I tried editing your question title to what I believe is the significantly more specific question you're trying to ask. Feel free to revert if I got it wrong.